# How can I close the connection before have received the response

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

In a simple code like this

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(request)
```

I have the need of not having the response from the host to arrive. Is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

I already tried writing

```
s.close()
```

but the responses arrive

P.S. the host I connect to is a proxy, if it's useful to say.
so even if the response phisically comes from proxy, in reality it is natively generated by the site (not the proxy, the proxy is the intermediate). so i need to not listen the answer, the response of proxy. Just need to send the request

Comment: Why not use UDP as the protocol then? You'd send a message without having to wait for a response. TCP, on the other hand, works on handshaking between hosts.

Comment: `set timeout` will be guide you, another point `all socket oject required try-except`

Comment: thanks for the answers but... it's not something related to the waiting and the timeout. I just need a way to block and to not listen the response. The response mustn't arrive.

Comment: the host I connect to is a proxy, if it's useful to say.

Comment: so even if the response phisically comes from proxy, in reality it is natively generated by the site (not the proxy, the proxy is the intermediate). so i need to not listen the answer, the response of proxy. Just need to send the request